# mutate data frame on the basis of text in another column

Tags: r

Actually i want to change the data frame on the basis of column Region.

i want to check the column Regions if there is any text in column house for "!UK" in region and for that add a new row and paste the text in new row in column house.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <-  tibble(Region = c("AU","USA","CA","USA","!UK","AU","USA","CA","!UK"),
              lock = c(1,1,NA,1,NA,1,NA,1,NA),
              type= c("sale",NA,NA,"target","target",NA,"sale",NA,"target"),
              House =c("Tagore house","Gandhi house",NA,"Flexible;Tagore house;Gandhi house","Tagore house",NA,"Flexible;Gandhi house","Gandhi house","Gandhi house"))
```

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: updated the expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm inferring that row order matters. Since you have nothing that would imply that, we'll add one.

```r
library(dplyr)
df <- mutate(df, rn = row_number())
df %>%
  filter(Region == "!UK") %>%
  transmute(House, rn = rn - 0.1) %>%
  bind_rows(df, .) %>%
  mutate(House = if_else(Region %in% "!UK", House[NA], House)) %>%
  arrange(rn)
# # A tibble: 11 × 5
#    Region  lock type   House                                 rn
#    <chr>  <dbl> <chr>  <chr>                              <dbl>
#  1 AU         1 sale   Tagore house                         1  
#  2 USA        1 <NA>   Gandhi house                         2  
#  3 CA        NA <NA>   <NA>                                 3  
#  4 USA        1 target Flexible;Tagore house;Gandhi house   4  
#  5 <NA>      NA <NA>   Tagore house                         4.9
#  6 !UK       NA target <NA>                                 5  
#  7 AU         1 <NA>   <NA>                                 6  
#  8 USA       NA sale   Flexible;Gandhi house                7  
#  9 CA         1 <NA>   Gandhi house                         8  
# 10 <NA>      NA <NA>   Gandhi house                         8.9
# 11 !UK       NA target <NA>                                 9
```

You can then `select(-rn)` if needed (I kept it for explanatory purposes only).

Comment: if i have text like !uk or !uk_1, !uk_store  like this and i am trying matches(!uk_) but stil not working any solution..??

Comment: have you tried `grepl("!UK", Region, ignore.case=TRUE)`?

Comment: `matches` is for use within tidyselect verbs like `select` and `across`, it is not appropriate for filtering rows. You can use `grepl("!UK", Region)`, `startsWith(Region, "!UK")`, or more strictly `substr(Region, 1, 3) == "!UK"`.

Comment: tried all but when updating the same in your suggested code , then its not working. can you please suggest what i am doing wrong

Comment: No, apparently your real data is different enough that your sample data is not representative enough. With the sample data you provided, replacing `Region == "!UK"` with each of the above snippets works for me without problem; I suggest you update the sample data in your question with data that does not work given the code I've provided.